# String manipulation first character and number

Tags: java

I have a string "shyam123-rohan-jack75"

I want to have output like "S123-r-j75"

Basically if, Print the first character of string and if there is a intiger part in a word we have to print it as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What are the rules?

Answer (score 1):

Using `String#replaceAll`:

```
String input = "shyam123-rohan-jack75";
input = input.replaceAll("\\b([A-Za-z])[A-Za-z]*", "$1");
System.out.println(input);
```

This prints:

```
s123-r-j75
```

This regex approach works by matching and capturing the first alphabet character following a word boundary.  It also matches all following alphabet characters (but not numbers), replacing with just the first captured alphabet.

Comment: Tim, you are too kind.  Do you think the OP can convert the first char to uppercase?

Comment: The leading `S` almost looks like a typo to me.